# Proof of Cauchy-Schwarz integral for equality

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, proof-explanation, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, cauchy-integral-formula

Suppose $f,g:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ are integrable and continuous functions. I want to show that $$\bigg(\int_{a}^{b}f(x)g(x)\,dx\bigg)^2=\int_{a}^{b}f^2(x)\,dx\int_{a}^{b}g^2(x)\,dx $$ if and only if there exists a $k\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=kg(x)$.

For the backwards direction, I cannot see why the assumption that $f$ and $g$ is continuous is necessary. I have thought about some step functions where they are not continuous, but I cannot find an example which shows why this is necessary. This direction however, is much more straightforward than the forwards direction.

I believe that the forwards direction is a special case of the elementary Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, where $$\big(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ib_i\big)^2=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^2\sum_{i=1}^{n}b_i^2$$ I am just unsure why, again, the hypothesis that $f,g$ be continuous functions is necessary. I think has something to do with the type of partition one can choose, possibly regular partitions are viable for all continuous functions.

Could someone explain $(1)$ why the assumption that $f$ and $g$ are continuous is necessary and/or $(2)$ how I should choose a partition for this proof. I am using the Darboux definition of an integral.

Comment: If you change the value of of one of the functions at one point then the values of the integrals do no change. So you still have the equality but $f=kg$ fails at that point. So continuity is necessary.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy but this implies that the implications are false. you have just given a counter example, right? like if $f=kg$ except at finitely many points in $[a,b]$, then equality still holds.

Comment: Yes,  am giving a counter-example to the claim that the result is true for R-integrable functions even without continuity.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy ok thank you. I was trying to weave in continuity into my arguments when I was proving it, and I couldn't figure out where to use it. So it really only goes one way for this one. if $f=kg$, then equality holds, but the converse isn't necessarily true.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy wait, but if they are continuous, then how do I use that in my argument?

Comment: Just a nit, but $g=0$ also gives equality, even though there may not be any $k$, say if $f=x$.

Comment: The correct conclusion is either $f=kg$ for some constant $k$ or $g=kf$ for some constant $k$. OP: the proof is based on the fact if $h$ is a non-negative continuous function with $\int_a^{b}f(x)dx=0$ then $f(x) =0$ for all $x$. Continuity is essential here.

Comment: Does this help?: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz_Inequality/Definite_Integrals